# Removing All rows with improper data

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I need to remove the rows of data in data frame that have been entered incorrectly for example I have a column of countries. I need to delete all the values that are not counties. I know the list of countries that should be there. 
For example I would want to delete the row containing a numeric value as a country. 
Here is my attempt:

```
currency_list <- c("GBP","HKD","AUD","NZD","USD")
KS_2016.update$currency[KS_2016.update$currency =currency_list]
```

Comment: Please also show the input and output, and explain how the output differs from the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `subset` it with `%in%` and `!`

```
subset(KS_2016.update, !currency %in% currency_list)
```

---

Or use `filter` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
KS_2016.update %>%
        filter(!currency %in% currency_list)
```

Comment: You're awesome!